# Count rows that have at least one associated item

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

- `sales`, which are purchases from a store
- `items`, which are all the items the store carries
- `sale_items`, which associate `sales` to the `items` bought in that sale. So a  row in `sale_items` has both a `sale_id` and an `item_id`.

What is the most efficient way to find all `sales` that include a `sale_item` corresponding to a given `item`?

My first guess was

```
select sale_id, item_id, count(*)
from sales as s
join sale_items as si on si.sale_id=s.id
group by item_id
order by count(*) desc
```

But then if a given `sale` had multiple `sale_items` with the same `item`, that `sale` is counted multiple times. That's not what I want--I only want to count the `sales` themselves.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I find this a bit confusing. You first ask for `all sales that include...` and then you're counting stuff. You're also joining with sale_items and then you say you `only want to count the sales themselves`. Could you provide at least the columns of what you're expecting to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to find the number of sales that included a specific item:

```
SELECT count(distinct(sale_id)) FROM sale_items
WHERE item_id='<your_item_id>'
```